# Why is javac still need when compiling with maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, maven, javac, maven-compiler-plugin

I read about this the [`maven-compiler-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/non-javac-compilers.html). On the linked page, it told:

> Currently, the Compiler Plugin is bundled with the `javac` compiler artifact with artifactId `plexus-compiler-javac`, which can be seen as one of the dependencies declared inside the Compiler Plugin's POM

According to my understanding, we do not need the local `javac` anymore, say on my local operating system, mere `JRE` instead of `JDK` is enough.

I did try to remove `JDK` and installed only `JRE` on my local system. However, when I tried to compile with `maven` with command `mvn clean compile`, there was the error message -

`No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?`

Could anyone explain why is it so? Probably my understanding is wrong?

Comment: "According to my understanding, we do not need the local javac anymore." well yeah, unless you want to **compile** something.

Comment: @Kayaman my understanding is: if I want to compile something, the `plexus-compiler-javac` should be able to be used in place of local `javac`

Comment: What part of *your undersanding is wrong and based on a wrong **assumption** based on mis-reading the documentation*?

Comment: What part of 'contrary to this plugin's name, the Compiler Plugin does not compile the sources of your project by itself' didn't you understand? It is the first line of the documentation you cited.

Comment: Read the entire documentation for comprehension next time. Emphasis is mine; ***Contrary to this plugin's name, the Compiler Plugin does not compile the sources of your project by itself.** To compile, the Compiler Plugin uses another class to compile them. The parameter compilerId determines which class will be used. Currently, the Compiler Plugin is bundled with the javac compiler artifact with artifactId plexus-compiler-javac, which can be seen as one of the dependencies declared inside the Compiler Plugin's POM.*

Comment: You still need the Oracle Java compiler, which is in the JDK, not in the JRE, and not available separately from Maven Central.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-compiler/) :

> Plexus Compiler
>
> Plexus Compiler is a Plexus component to **use** different compilers
>   through a uniform API.
>
> Contrary to this plugin's name, the Compiler Plugin does not compile the sources of your project by itself.

So the `plexus-compiler-javac` artifact has to be considered as a `wrapper` to compile.
It is not stated that it contains the `javac` program.

To be exact, from the 3.0 version, it is not directly `javac` any longer that is by default used but `javax.tools` (more particularly `javax.tools.JavaCompiler`).
The [`maven-compiler-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/index.html) documentation states indeed :

> Since 3.0, the default compiler is **javax.tools.JavaCompiler** (if you
>   are using java 1.6) and is used to compile Java sources. If you want
>   to force the plugin using `javac`, you must configure the plugin option
>   forceJavacCompilerUse

You have to understand that the Maven core plugin will not reinvent the wheel and guess what you need.
To compile java classes you need a Java compiler and generally you want to able to ensure that you are using a specific Java compiler as OS and Java version matter.
So the maven compiler plugin needs and uses a JDK under the hood.

Comment: We did compilations with Maven using plain JRE - which doesn't have javac 
 - and the plexus Eclipse compiler plugin - this was back around version 3.5.   For projects which _really_ need long term support this is a viable option.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - that is because Eclipse includes a **non-standard** compiler of it its own in older versions. Maven never included `javac`. Not sure about now because I switched to Intellij as soon as it came out.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I am not sure that "*non-standard*" compiler is the right term.  They wrote their own but the byte code format is well defined so it typically does not matter which compiler did the work.  Those working in Eclipse use it all the time.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33165304/53897 demonstrates how to use it with maven.  An additional feature is that it allows for compilation of very old code with new releases of Java where javac will not anymore.    I am not advocating either; competition is healthy in compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is not a java compiler. Maven runs the java compiler for you and configures all the paths.

When you run mvn -X compile you will see the compiler details.

In conclusion: you need a java compiler installed to compile java - even when maven starts the compiler for you.

Comment: Thanks first for your answer :) Then what is the purpose of `plexus-compiler-javac` dependency in the *maven-compiler-plugin*? In my opinion, `plexus-compiler-javac` should be able to be used in place of local `javac`. But seems that my understanding is wrong. If I am wrong, I wish anyone can help modify my understanding :)

Comment: **NO** that artifact is the one that supports `javac` it says nothing about including the `javac` executable which would be impossible to do in a platform neutral way. Think about it, use some common sense.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Great! Thanks a lot for your explanation :) You can answer it formally then I will check it :) (Y)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I am not native English speaker but when I see "Plugin is bundled with the `javac`" it gives me impression that `javac` may be also *provided* with plugin, not that it just *uses* available `javac`.

Comment: @Pshemo There's a lot more to see than that. See the *first line* of the document he cited.

Comment: @Pshemo - you like the OP are taking part of a complete sentance and paragraph out of content. Here is the complete context; ***Contrary to this plugin's name, the Compiler Plugin does not compile the sources of your project by itself.** To compile, the Compiler Plugin uses another class to compile them. The parameter compilerId determines which class will be used. Currently, the Compiler Plugin is bundled with the javac compiler artifact with artifactId plexus-compiler-javac, which can be seen as one of the dependencies declared inside the Compiler Plugin's POM.*