# Java hot-code-replace fails on static methods

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, hot-code-replace

Hot code replace works for me on instance methods, but  not on static methods. I get this error 
[image]

Note that I am simply adding a `println` to the body of a `static private` or even `public` method, not changing any method modifiers,  as suggested by the error message.  How do I achieve this hot replacement?

I am using Eclipse Oxygen and Java 8 JRE. 
Maven `com.google.cloud.tool:appengine-maven-plugin` is used to launch app in debug mode with goal
`appengine:run`. I then connect with the Eclipse remote debugger.

Comment: A `static private` method can be optimized, e. g. by inlining where it is called. Does the method exist in the bytecode? If not, _Hot Code Replace_ cannot find the method to replace.

Comment: Good point But this behavior occurs for all static methods, including public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Hot Code Replace, the [whole class file is replaced](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/enhancements1.4.html#hotswap). To find out the exact reason why the files cannot be exchanged, you would have to compare the original bytecode with the one to be changed.

By default, Maven uses `javac` for compiling, whereas the file to be swapped is compiled with Eclipse's own Java compiler. Different optimizations can lead to the classes file not being swappable, especially if private methods, fields or constants are used.

One of the following might solve your issue:

- [Using the Eclipse compiler in the Maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33164976/6505250)
- Making all private methods, fields and constants `protected`

Comment: Using the Eclipse compiler in the Maven build did it for me! Specifically, adding  <configuration>
          <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>

Comment: The key is to have the same compiler -- we were using an external JDK to compile, which differed from Eclipse's internal compiler.