# Is it possible to use Eclipse JDT static analysis for null annotations when compiling from the command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, null, static-analysis, null-safety

Is it possible to use Eclipse's JDT static analysis for null annotations when compiling from the command line? I have a pre-annotated codebase and want to leverage the work that has already been done without having to launch an IDE just to examine the result.

I made a small test program:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull;
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @Nullable Integer a = test();
        
        // NullPointerException
        a.notify();
    }
    
    public static @NonNull Integer test() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And compiled from the command line:

```
javac -cp org.eclipse.jdt.annotation-2.2.800.jar Main.java
```

However, no errors are reported.

Is it possible to use these annotations outside of the Eclipse environment?

Comment: You need to use the Eclipse compiler for Java (ecj) instead of `javac`: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_batch_compiler.htm (for Maven see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33164976/6505250)).